# Chat widget that supports Open ID login

Tags: chat

I am looking for an embeddable live chat widget (like [Shoutmix](http://www.shoutmix.com/main/)) that allows users to sign in using open ID before starting the chat. Any ideas?

Most of the ones I've come across - Olark, Shoutmix, Shoutjax etc just require the user to add a username. I would like to give the user the option to sign in before chatting.

Answer (score 1):

we (Olark) don't do OpenID directly inside the chatbox yet, but we do have an API for integrating single sign-on like OpenID.  If you enable OpenID on your own site, you can drop that information into Olark nicknames and buddy statuses (via updateVisitorNickname and updateVisitorStatus).  Check out [olark.com/docs](http://www.olark.com/docs)

Comment: Thanks Matt. Do you have any plans on allowing openID in the chatbox anytime soon? We currently don't have sign in on our site - so if Olark could support Open ID before someone starts chatting, it would be perfect.

Comment: we don't have any immediate plans, but I just added it as a feature request in our tracker :)  I think it may still make the most sense as an Olark extension, but we'll see.  Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenId to login to [Wablet](http://wablet.com/).  It also integrates all of your chat/IM accounts. The only problem is that it is in Private Alpha at the moment.